# Knockout.js text binding multiple properties into a single <p> node

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding

I need to bind a `<p>` tag to a value in my view-model.
Now normally this is not the issue, but in this case, the value is separated into multiple fields within the model, because it is an address.

So I have the "streetName" and "HouseNumber" as separate fields, but they both need to be shown in the HTML as a part of this

tag.

**According to knockout.js's** [official documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-syntax.html):

"The binding value can be a **single value**, variable, or literal or **almost any valid JavaScript expression**."

Now I notice the "almost" there, so I am reserved, but a simple string concatenation should be considered a "simple enough operation" yes? I need to bind the value of my `<p>` tag to the values of two string fields within the model, what syntax would I use since the one I am trying is not working:

`<p data-bind="text: dataBind1 + dataBind2"></p>`

On a sidenote dataBind1 and dataBind2 are not really that simple, it is a nested function call, yadda, yadda, yadda, though they work perfectly fine when separated, I cannot, for the death of me get them to work when I want them "together" in a single element. Real bind values are:

`<p data-bind="text: getModelData(processID).Property()[0].Street + getModelData(processID).Property()[0].HouseNumber"></p>`

### EDIT (To clarify the viewModel's structure a bit):

The view model itself is a JavaScript object (`var viewModel`) which has certain methods, such as getModelData(ID), updateModelData(ID) and such. The ID being passed here is a "unique controller identifier" for the controllers of different parts of the page. There is some 1:1 vs 1:M mummbo jumbo here, but it is not relevant. The `var viewModel` receives the information from an AJAX call and dynamically update's itself with additional properties, based on which controllers are jammed into the page. So it would have the "uniqueID" properties which are in fact, the knockout's view models.
This way all the view models are kept under the 'interface' of a single object. Something like this:

```
  var viewModel = {
        uniqueID: object, //knockout.js viewModel of Controller1
        uniqueID2: object, //knockout.js viewModel of Controller2
        getModelData(processID): function(){
           //does stuff
        }
    }
```

So in this case accessing the `getModelData(ID).Property()[0].Street` would be pretty much the same as accessing `Property()[0].Street` in a regular non-deep-nested model or whatever you want to call it. And the structure of the knockout object itself is somewhat similar to:

```
{
    Property: [
    {
        Street: "someStreet1"
        HouseNumber: "someNumber1"
    },
    {
        Street: "someStreet2"
        HouseNumber: "someNumber2"
    },
    {
        Street: "someStreet3"
        HouseNumber: "someNumber3"
    },
    ]

}
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in the expression for one. (trailing plus sign). Also, it would be helpful to include the javascript viewmodel for a fully reproducible sample.

Comment: javascript view model is dynamically generated and private in nature (closures) thus I have no way of accessing it, the trailing + is a mistype I made here, there is none in the code used on the page. I can verify that both bindigns work when separated because I made 2 additional elements and bound 1 of these bindings to each and those work. I will provide more info tomorrow (maybe even an answer) been thumping at this for 3 hours now, cannot look at code anymore or I will gouge my eyes out.

Comment: Putting your actual question to one side for a second, my first thought is that your view knows far too much about the underlying model - consider abstracting out a sub-model for your view, so the view doesn't need to know about `getModelData(processID).Property()[0].Street`, and instead is just `Street`.

Comment: Hmm, @JamesThorpe it is a valid point, will think it through. Currently this model gets updated dynamically and it is all a big mess, everything is created dynamically on the server side as well, so it just drags chains of meta-data along with it. There are actually multiple "view models" embedded into a single JS object, I will talk it through with my team, thanks for the tip.

Comment: You say that you cannot get them to work; what error are you seeing? Is the binding present but not what is expected? Are you getting an unhandled exception at applyBindings()? Are you seeing in the rendered HTML something like function dependentObservable() { [native code] }? More details are needed to triage

Comment: Also, what are the contents of getModelData() in this specific instance?  Is the return value of the AJAX call assigned to an observable or simply returned as an array? (This matters because you're accessing Property() like an observable but haven't indicated it is one.) Further, is getModelData() returning anything at all? Use a foreach binding to verify that you are getting data: "<div data-bind="foreach: getModelData(processID)"><ul data-bind="foreach: Property"><li data-bind="text: Street"></li></ul></div>"

Answer (score 3):

You have to send a value, function (that returns a value), or an expression.

**Example:**

```
<p data-bind="text: (dataBind1() + dataBind2())"></p>
```

This **SHOULD** cause the evaluation to re-run on an observable update. I only know of a few cases that it will not.

Additionally you can use a computed value which guarantees the observable updates will re-compute the value. This also keeps logic out of the markup and is better for the newer browser security policies. See @Matt.kaaj's answer for that solution.

Finally you can use child elements like a `span` which will not affect the markup and will be the most semantically correct.

```
<p><span data-bind="text: dataBind1"></span> <span data-bind="text: dataBind2"></span></p>
```

Comment: Using span would be more semantically correct in this case? Proper semantics is the first reason why I am trying to avoid it. If it is a <p> it's a <p> in a sense, I do not think separating the Street Name and a Number would make a lot of sense. Correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: Also @MattSizzle, I updated the question with a 'pseudo' view model and how it works here. You say that it has to send a value, but what is a string if not a value, well technically it's an object-literal but, is this the reason it does not work? How would I make my "someStreet" into a value that would be acceptable for the binding?

Comment: It's syntactically correct according to MDN's document on <span>. It's common to use span tags for individual bindings in this manner.  Alternatively, you could write "<p><!-- ko text: someStreet --><!-- /ko>&nbsp;<!-- ko text: someNumber --><!-- /ko --></p>" but that's definitely not as readable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you have your View Model but here is what you can do.

```
 var MainViewModel = function (){
    var self = this;
    self.Street = ko.observable(getModelData(processID).Property()[0].Street);
    self.HouseNum = ko.observable(getModelData(processID).Property()[0].HouseNumber);

    self.FullAddress= ko.computed(function () {
        return self.Street() + ", " + self.HouseNum();
     });
 }
```

HTML

```
<p data-bind="text: FullAddress"></p>
```

Comment: Hmmm, question, the 'self' object in this case would have to belong to the exact same ViewModel object that gets it's bindings applied to, yes? Updating the initial question with a rough schematic of the view model

Comment: Correct. `this` basically assign to the variable which here in knockout it is common to use `self` to say that `this` is referring to the particular View model object.Since `this` can refer to different objects depending on context.